# Promisify an event handler

Tags: javascript, typescript, async-await, promise, nestjs

I am trying to use `https://github.com/yfinkelstein/node-zookeeper` to connect to zookeeper server.
node-zookeeper uses EventEmitter's `on` function to allow using the zookeeper client when it connects successfully.

```js
this.client.on('connect', async () => {
  console.log('connected successfully');
  // fetch data from zookeeper by supplying path
  const data = await client.get('/config', false);
  console.log(data); 
 });
```

But this does not allow me to return the data.
If this data represents configuration, it is important to be able to return it.
I tried promisifying using bluebird but no luck.

How can I promisify it (or any other way that would allow me to return the values).

Comment: What do you mean by "return the data"? Is it being stored in the `data` variable correctly? Do you want to access it from outside of the connect event listener?

Comment: @grimsteel yes, i can log tha data correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to access `data` from outside of the event listener, you can use the `Promise` constructor:

```js
const data = await new Promise(resolve => 
  this.client.on('connect', async () => {
    console.log('connected successfully');
    // fetch data from zookeeper by supplying path
    resolve(await client.get('/config', false));
  })
);
console.log(data);
```

Comment: Lol I had tried similar things but could not get it to work. But your snippet worked. Thanks.